# removeClass() jquery on mobile not working

Tags: jquery, mobile

I create event onclick jquery to send a request, and after getting the result, handler onclick check if the result true then remove class from div. In desktop everything is fine but when I try on mobile, it's not working.

Here are some code I used.

```
<div class="programme">
    <input title="id" type="hidden" id="programme-id" value="{{ p.id }}">
    <div class="programme-name">
        <h6><a href="link" target="_blank">name</a></h6>
    </div>
    <span class="programme-separator"></span>
    <div class="programme-love programme-loved" id="love-programme"></div>
</div>
```

Jquery code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#love-programme', function(){
        var url = "url";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function(data){
                if(data == '1'){
                    $('#love-programme').removeClass('programme-loved');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Is there anyone has a clue what's wrong with it, I would appreciate it much. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I feel click event is not triggering in mobile. Can you put an alert and check?

Comment: It's triggered, I've checked it. Is background-image can be a problem? because I define different background-image for both programme-love and programme-loved.

Comment: I got it, it happens because I set the same background-image between programme-love:hover and programme-loved. So it looks like not change, but actually change, it just sets hover on mobile.

Comment: Congrats buddy.. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove like:

You are using wrong class `programme-loved` instead of `programme-love`..

```
$("#love-programme").attr("class", "programme-love");
```

OR,

```
$("#love-programme").removeAttr('class').addClass('programme-love');
```

Comment: Sorry I edit my question. I just try the first one. Still not work on mobile.